# Is it possible to read a text or spreadsheet file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I want to load and parse files (.txt, .csv, .xls, even .json) from a basic (HTML5/CSS3/jQuery) web site/app. Is this possible, or do security concerns prevent such? If it is possible, does anybody have any sample code showing how to accomplish it?

Note: I'm talking about a user uploading a file from their machine - not a file sitting on the web server / not a file that is part of the site's data.

Comment: jquery.load()?: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Vikram as ar as I know, jQuery doesn't parse that loaded file. *After* load you should be able to do what you want with the content though.

Comment: ofcourse you dont have a custom .csv, .txt and .xls parser...but json is native to JS and hence available

Comment: As long it's on the same domain or the server supports CORS, or the format is JSONP, it's no problem at all, just get the files with a XMLHttpRequest and parse them anyway you'd like

Comment: @Clay...once you have the data loaded, then you can parse it process it the way you like......you would have a 3rd party parser for .csv (in Javascript) or you write your own parser for parsing the text you have loaded...

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about a user uploading a file from their machine - not a file sitting on the server. I'll update my question with that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API to open a local file on the client side.

Parsing the plain text files should be easy using the appropriate tool:

- [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for .json files
- Regex for TXT and CSV files

Not sure about XLS, though.

---

If you want to parse the file server-side (which I assumed you didn't), just use an `<input type="file"/>`.

Comment: The FileReader link tells me, "Not Found

The requested URL /en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader was not found on this server."

Comment: @ClayShannon: That's because the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is down for maintenance right now. This might be the documentation Thomas was directing you to: http://dochub.io/#dom/filereader (found via searching on the link from MDN's maintenance message)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the .xls file format is written exactly, but the others you mention should be able to be parsed rather easily (e.g. splitting on newlines/whitespace, commas and semicolons): [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

As for getting the files, an [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a text file is straightforward.  There are libraries available for parsing [CSV](https://github.com/mbostock/dsv) and [XLS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls) files.

You can read client data using HTML5 file api or XHR.  For example, the XLS library has a [HTML5 File API demo](http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xls/)